# Как создать глобальную переменную на TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Я пытаюсь создать переменную, которую можно будет использовать в любой части проекта.

При использовании:

```
global.test = 5;
```

Возникает ошибка:

> Свойство "test" не существует в типе "Global".

Я знаю что использовать глобальные - это зло, но мне нужно это.

Comment: front или back?

Comment: Не понял...
Что значит front или back?

Comment: ЛОЛ, если дословно - перед или зад

Comment: А для тех кто в танке - нода или браузер?

Comment: Нода, я браузерный js никогда не использовал.

Comment: global['test'] = 5;

Comment: (global as any).test = 5;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## В последних версиях создание глобальной переменной изменилось

Многие ответы устарели. Если вы используете Node.js не забудьте установить @types/node последней версии. И так, вот как теперь нужно делать:

```typescript
export {};

declare global {
    var qwaVar: string;
}
```

И всё, теперь можете обращаться к переменной qwaVar через global или window (в зависимости от того какое у вас окружение):

```typescript
console.log(global.qwaVar)
```

Не забудьте только в начале файла с `declare global` поставить `export {}`, это нужно для того чтобы ваш файл считался за модуль (или что-то вроде того). Эту декларацию можно положить в отдельный файл, как я это и сделал:

#### g.ts

```typescript
/* eslint-disable no-var */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
export {};

declare global {
    var nodeVersion: string;
}
```

#### index.ts

```typescript
global.nodeVersion = process.versions.node;
console.log(global.nodeVersion);
```

Answer (score 2):

#### package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.13.4",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

#### q.ts

```
namespace NodeJS {
    export interface Global {
        readonly qwaConst: string
        qwaVar: string
    }
}

global.qwaVar = ""
//@ts-ignore
global.qwaConst = ""
```

#### index.ts

```
import './q' // не забываем первым делом импортировать файл с инициализацией глобальных переменных, желательно констант
// import '...' затем уже остальные


global.qwaConst
global.qwaVar
```

### @types/node

`node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts` ->
`namespace NodeJS` -> `interface Global`

#### расширить можно так

```
namespace NodeJS {
    export interface Global {
        readonly qwaConst: string
        qwaVar: string
    }
}
```

#### ещё немного примеров

- [Там](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35074713/4794368)

### globalThis

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)
- [www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#type-checking-for-globalthis)